# How to create a flatlist with infinite scroll with local data? (Possible useState misuse)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jsx, react-native-flatlist

I have a problem trying to create a FlatList with infinite scroll using local data. I want the list to load 20 different elements every time it reaches the bottom. Here is the list:

```
                <FlatList
                  contentContainerStyle={styles.airportLatestSearchlist}
                  data={filteredAirportList}
                  renderItem={renderAirportItem}
                  keyExtractor={(item) =>
                    filteredAirportList.indexOf(item).toString()
                  }
                  onEndReached={increaseTotalFilteredResults}
                  onEndReachedThreshold={0.1}
                />
```

The data **filteredAirportList** is loaded once the user starts typing in the search box. This is the function that filters the data which is already stored.

```
  const filterAirportSearch = (value) => {
    const managedValue = value.toLowerCase();
    const filteringAirports = airportList.filter(
      (airport) =>
        airport.airport_name?.toLowerCase().includes(managedValue) ||
        airport.city?.toLowerCase().includes(managedValue) ||
        airport.country?.toLowerCase().includes(managedValue) ||
        airport.icao?.toLowerCase().includes(managedValue) ||
        airport.iata?.toLowerCase().includes(managedValue),
    );
    var numberListHelper = filteringAirports;
    numberListHelper.length = numberElementsList;
    setTotalFilteredAirportList(filteringAirports);
    setFilteredAirportList(numberListHelper);
  };
```

And this is the function that is called once the user scrolls to the bottom:

```
  const increaseTotalFilteredResults = () => {
    let numberHelper = numberElementsList;
    if (numberHelper < totalFilteredAirportList.length) {
      numberHelper = numberElementsList + 20;
    }
    setNumberElementsList(numberHelper);

    if (Object.keys(totalFilteredAirportList).length > 0) {
      let filteredListUpdate = totalFilteredAirportList;
      filteredListUpdate.length = numberHelper;
      setFilteredAirportList(filteredListUpdate);
    }
  };
```

However, every time that this function is called:

> numberListHelper.length = numberElementsList;

It changes the length for the **filteringAirports** state as well and I can't load the rest of the data. Is it actually a bug or am I changing directly by a reference?

Here is a visual part of the problem.

**Before .length is called**
[image: Before .length is called]

**After .length is called**
[image: After .length is called]

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you do `newArr = oldArr` you are just copying the reference, so any change you make to any of them will be reflected in both, if you want to clone an array do this instead

```js
let numberListHelper = [...filteringAirports]
```

Comment: That is right. I totally forgot about that. Thanks!